# Google Dataflow warning `Rpc to InMemory completed with error ABORTED: Evicted due to staleness`

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Our google cloud dataflow jobs are throwing below warnings:

- Rpc to InMemory completed with error ABORTED: Evicted due to staleness
- Rpc to job-vqmu-harness-9lss:12345 completed with error DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline Exceeded

Unable to find what these error mean.

Answer (score 0):

The errors seem to be very generic and can be red herrings.

If you need support for a specific project, please file a [support](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/getting-support) ticket to Google Dataflow.